# Count number of times an item appears in a list C#

Tags: c#, list, streamreader

It's suppose to allow the user to choose a team from the ListBox, click a button and display the number of times that team has won the World Series by referring to a .txt file (called World Series).

I'm trying to take the selected item and check how many times that selected item appears in the World Series .txt file.

Any pointers?

```
    private void compareList()
    {
        StreamReader champFile = File.OpenText("WorldSeries.txt");
        List<string> champList = new List<string>();
        string selectedTeam;

        while (!champFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            champList.Add(champFile.ReadLine());
        }
        while (teamList.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            selectedTeam = teamList.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        if (selectedTeam = champList???)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The " + selectedTeam + "has won the World Series " + champList.????.Count + "times! ")
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The " + selectedTeam + "has never won the World Series.")
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I was wondering if I could form an if statement by comparing selectedTeam to the "items" in champList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `File.ReadLines` and some `LINQ`

```
selectedTeam = teamList.SelectedItem.ToString();
var count = File.ReadLines("WorldSeries.txt")
           .Count(x => x.Contains(selectedTeam));


if(count > 0)
{
   MessageBox.Show("The " + selectedTeam + "has won the World Series " +  count + "times! ")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What is LINQ?

Comment: it's called Language-Integrated Query, if you hear this for first time you should definitely take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)

Comment: Oh wait. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and it says I'm using System.Linq already. I used this code and I have no errors!!! So I'm guessing this method should work now. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (teamList.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Please select an Item first!");
   return;
}

string selectedTeam = teamList.SelectedItem.ToString();
var count = File.ReadAllLines("WorldSeries.txt").Where(line => line ==selectedTeam).Count();

//var count = champList.Where(l=>l==selectedTeam).Count();

if (count >0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("The " + selectedTeam + "has won the World Series " + count  + "times! ");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("The " + selectedTeam + "has never won the World Series.")
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this gave me some errors when I tried it. :/

Comment: you need to add a reference to System.Linq

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simply this way

### Updated Code

```
if(teamList.SelectedIndex != 0 && champList.Contains(SelectedTeam))
{
MessageBox.Show("The " + selectedTeam + "has won the World Series " + champList.Where(w => w == SelectedItem).Count() + "times! ");
}
```

Comment: Oh awesome thank you. It says SelectedItem does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Yes the error says 'SelectedItem' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @Learnin2Code I Had updated my code now check it out May be it is gives error when SelectedIndex == 0

Answer (score 0):

Place the champList in a dictionary and increment a counter if they already exist.

```
private void compareList()
    {
        StreamReader champFile = File.OpenText("WorldSeries.txt");
        Dictionary<string, int> champList = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        string selectedTeam;
        string currentChamp;
        while (!champFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            currentChamp = champFile.ReadLine();
            if(champList.containsKey(currentChamp))
                champList.get(currentChamp) += 1;
            else
                champList.Add(champFile.ReadLine(), 1);
        }
        while (teamList.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            selectedTeam = teamList.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
        if (champList.hasKey(selectedTeam))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The " + selectedTeam + "has won the World Series " + champList.get(selectedTeam) + "times! ")
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The " + selectedTeam + "has never won the World Series.")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this code and got a few errors. I'm not familiar with using dictionary